# Graphite: series with constant calculation

Tags: graphite, grafana

I have a metric that represents a hit ratio of my DB.

I want a graph showing the miss ratio (1 - hit_ratio)

Is there a way do do that in graphite?

Basically the question is how to calculate:

1 - *series with wildcards*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `offset(scale(some.series.*, -1), 1)`.